# How to deploy web application involving Strapi

Tags: reactjs, deployment, strapi

I have created full stack ecommerce application and i want to deploy it.
But since it involve React as Frontend and Strapi as Backend I don't know the procedure, how to launch. Could you please help me on this and guide.

Thanks,

I tried other resource to find out how to do it, they are so confusing.